# How to implement breadth first search to find degrees of separation between two people in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, node.js, graph-algorithm

I tried to use C# but in javascript I couldnt do it(data is in JSON object in property array). Please help! Thank you.
The degrees between a person and himself is always 0
The degrees between friends is 1 and so on
If there is no chain between two people, their degree is defined to be -1

Comment: var JsonDatabase = {
peoples: {
1: {
 id: 1,
name: 'name1',
age: 20,
                   
friends: [4,3]
},
2: {
id: 2,
name: 'name2',
age: 21,
                    
friends: [1,3]
},
        
3: {
id: 3,
name: 'name3',
age: 22,
                    
friends: []
},
        
4: {
id: 4,
name: 'name4',
age: 23,
                    
 friends: [1,2]
  }
        
 }
};
        
function friends(source, desitnation)
{
         
}

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piBq7VD0ZSo here a resource that I think can get you going.

Comment: //can i convert this to javascript 
int levels = 2;
HashSet<people>[] friendsPerLevel = new HashSet<people>[levels];
friendsPerLevel[0] = new HashSet<User>(currentUser.Friends);
for(int i = 1; i < levels; i++) {
friendsPerLevel[i] = new HashSet<people>();
foreach(people previousFriend in friendsPerLevel[i - 1]) {
 foreach(people friend in previousFriend.Friends) {
   bool exists = false;
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
 if(friendsPerLevel[j].Contains(friend)) {
exists = true;
  break;
   }
 }
 if(exists == false) {
        friendsPerLevel[i].Add(friend)
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Raj Add clarification, especially code, to the question itself using [edit]. It's impossible to read that stuff in comments that can't be properly formatted.